# Moving files based on string within the file name in python

Tags: python, automation

I am trying to use os.walk to move through a directory and find files that have a specific string in the filename and move them to other folders. So far I can use os.walk to look through things and find filenames fine but I am not sure on how to select based on the string I am looking for in the filenames and move them accordingly.

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Dillon\Desktop\Arid West')

dest = r'C:\Users\Dillon\Desktop\Arid West\Target Folder'

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r'C:\Users\Dillon\Desktop\Arid West'):
    source = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Dillon\Desktop\Arid West')
    print('Current Path:', dirpath)
    print('Directories: ', dirnames)
    print('Files: ', filenames)

if 'somestring' in filenames:
    shutil.move(source, dest)
```

Comment: Make sure your 'if 'somestring' in filenames:' is idented correctly inside your for loop

Comment: Are you on Python 3.6+? If you are, consider using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Your code will become cleaner and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
import os 
os.chdir(r'yourdir')
dest = r'yourdest'
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r'yourdir'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if 'somestring' in filename:
            shutil.move(dirpath + filename, dest)
```

Comment: this gives an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Dillon\\Desktop\\Arid West\\LC08_CU_008009_20140902_20190504_C01_V01_SRLC08CU0080092014090220190504C01V01_B1.tif'`